# ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error on Apache 2.2.22 Server

Tags: apache-2.2

i have problems with my Apache 2.2.22 Web Server. When i open it, i get a ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error. I have tried:

> SetEnv force-no-vary
>
> SetEnv downgrade-1.0
>
> SetEnv no-gzip 1
>
> zlib.output_compression = On

But nothing worked. When i added zlib.output_compression = On, my index page shown random chars.

Comment: I also forgot to say, it started yesterday

Comment: I unset the Accept-Encoding Header, and the site opens, but it is slow as my old Core 2 Duo. I guess there is a G-Zip or Deflating error, or the header indicates it is compress, but the compression fails and the plaintext is sent, but a browser cant decompress plain text right?